# How to set/assign data type just reading CSV file in scala without knowing its schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

**I have CSV file but i have to assign data type without knowing its data type & schema
i mean everything is done via scala programing is it possible??**
i don't know how to write code in scala any one know?

I am new to scala i just have basic idea about scala i know how to read csv file but i don't have its schema and data type is it possible? 
could you give me answer like this
1)loading csv file.
2)how to analysis using sparkSQL.
3)how to set data type automatically in scala.

Comment: This question as it stands is too broad. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck? If you don't know anything about scala, then the solution is to start learning scala, and maybe ask some questions on issues with that as they come up.

Comment: Sorry Ethan! I have mentioned "i have basic knowledge of scala"
the problem is i have got an assignment on scala , 
problem statement :
first i have to load csv file using spark-shell(scala shell) 
and CSV file doesn't have its schema and data type. by default spark gave string as data type and _c0, _c1 as column name if we didn't mentioned these.!
so is there any way to assign different data type to column without knowing the schema , so when i load the csv file then data type(as int, float, string, as columns) must assign automatically!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you, I've been busy. It sounds like you've successfully loaded the code into spark, but can't figure out the types. Can you show us what code you have? Without knowing where precisely you're stuck or confused, it's difficult to help.

Comment: hey Ethan I have got an answer 
.option("InferSchema","True") for detecting its data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is infer schema, that you can add that in code as option.Do you needa code example ? I can provide scala code.

Comment: hey Thanks a lot